# Tor .exit with polipo from urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, tor

I am trying to use Tor with urllib2 and polipo. What I need is a way to switch to specific exit nodes while program is running.
I have set 'AllowDotExit 1' in /etc/tor/torrc and was trying the following approach:

```
import urllib2

proxy = '127.0.0.1'
port = '8118'

url='http://ifconfig.me.651d7ace80e0b53e6c05eb4db2491264f049df66.exit'

proxyurl = '%s:%s' % (proxy, port)
proxyhandler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxyurl})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxyhandler)

page = opener.open(url)
print 'Page opened.'
print page.read()
```

But what I am getting is:

```
    :!/usr/bin/env python tortest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tortest.py", line 18, in <module>
    page = opener.open(url, timeout=20)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 504: Connect to ifconfig.me.651d7ace80e0b53e6c05eb4db2491264f049df66.exit:80 failed: General SOCKS server failure
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

`General SOCKS server failure` could be anything. For example, your TOR node might not know how to *reach* the specified exit node. This happens a lot. The exit may be listed on one of the status pages, but still be unreachable from your tor node. Try a different exit, or retry it later. Often when you request a particular exit node, it takes some minutes to establish a link through the network.